# dynamic typed list in razor template

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, c#-4.0, razor

```
// this function working perfectly
public dynamic CountTable()
{
    return (from t in db.Users
            group t by t.Type into g
            select new
            {
                type = g.Key,
                count = g.Count(),
                ActiveGroups = (from t in g group t by t.Active into ag select new { active = ag.Key, count = ag.Count() })
            }).ToList();
}
```

---

```
    // and this loop working in MVC Controller
    foreach (dynamic uct in ur.CountTable())
    {
        int x = uct.count;
    }
```

But not working in template:

```
Line 12: @foreach (dynamic uct in ViewBag.ur.CountTable())
Line 13: {
Line 14:     int adet = uct.count;
Line 15: }
```

**Line 14: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'count'**

Why? What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous types are compiled into internal classes.

The standard binder used by `dynamic` will only bind to public members **of public classes**.
Therefore, you cannot use it with anonymous types from a different assembly.

For more information, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/12/18/passing-anonymous-objects-to-mvc-views-and-accessing-them-using-dynamic.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Cannot say for sure as I never use dynamic but I suspect that this is a situation which is not supported by the razor view engine. Although you can have a dynamic model and directly invoke properties on it.</strike>

For example the following works:

```
@foreach (dynamic uct in new[] { new { Name = "foo" } })
{
    <div>@uct.Name</div>
}
```

but if we move this into some static method somewhere else:

```
@foreach (dynamic uct in Foo.SomeStaticMethod())
{
    <div>@uct.Name</div>
}
```

it no longer works as I suspect razor converts automatically to object.

Instead of using dynamic I would recommend you defining a couple of types and work with strong types.

Comment: @SLaks, correct, your answer explains it very nicely. Thanks for pointing this out. It clears my confusion. I will update my answer to keep only the relevant part of it which is not to use dynamic.